# Any complete library for Jabber in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, xmpp

I'm looking for for a Jabber library for Delphi, I can see some COM based jabber components. But I'm looking for a real VCL library.

Somebody knows one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could compile the code that underlies Exodus into a VCL.  That code is called JOPL, and can be found at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/exodus/source/browse/#svn/trunk/jopl).

Comment: Unfortunately this project is not maintained

Answer (score 4):

The Jabber protocol (XMPP) is supported by [IP*Works's xmpp component](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/xmpp.aspx).

Comment: New [link](http://cdn.nsoftware.com/help/IP9/dlp/XMPP.htm) instead of broken. But this xmpp component is very tiny and not suitable for complex tasks.

Comment: The price on that thing is brutal :/

Answer (score 2):

There is a Delphi XMPP client in the "Delphi on Rails" project here: [dorXMPPClient.pas](http://code.google.com/p/delphionrails/source/browse/trunk/src/dorXMPPClient.pas)

Answer (score 0):

Bricksoft have VCL component for MSN,YAHOO,AIM,ICQ and Jabber/GTalk.

Pls visit our website http://www.imcomponents.com/ if you want to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Take care: Jopl is licensed as GPLv2. So, if you wanna doing a commercial work, you'll need another library...

Comment: Not necessarily true. If you do commercial work where the customer gets the source code anyway, use of GPL libraries is absolutely fine. Customer needs to be aware though that they can't distribute the executables without making available the source code. It's their choice to make whether that's possible or not.

Comment: Yep. The GPL doesnt restrict what you can do with code, only the conditions of redistribution. Your quite welcome to sell the app, but the customer must get the code and be able to redistribute the code himself. This means that as a developer-for-hire your free to use GPL code as long as the client gets that code and understands that they must redistribute the code if they give the software to someone else. This is fine if your just making apps for internal use apps or websites or whatever (Though the AGPL has a few extra rules)

Comment: Commercial work normally do only on binaries, not source. So if the intention is to do binary-only classic commercial  work, so GPL blocks that kind of work.

Comment: It would be a problem for creating closed source turnkey apps. However most commercial development is for bespoke one offs for clients, usually internal use only, and they'll want the code anyway. As long as they can live with the GPL its fine. As long as they dont distribute it outside their organization, they dont have to give away the code.