# Jabber / XMPP library for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, xmpp

I am looking for xmpp / jabber protocol implementation for Delphi 7. [IP*WORKS!](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/features.aspx) is one of solutions, but it is expensive. I saw [Any complete library for Jabber in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181987/any-complete-library-for-jabber-in-delphi) question and JOPL was the answer, but it is not for Delphi 7. What do you use for Jabber and Delphi 7?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at the Open Source XMPP client written in Delphi: Exodus. More info on the client here, http://www.jabberstudio.org/projects/exodus/project/view.php.  I'd imagine their code is either already modularized so you can use (depending on license suitability) or you can rip it out and make it a module.  Not as ideal as an off-the-shelf library, but should work.

Comment: Exodus is not for Delphi 7. It requires at least 2006 version.