# facebook chat in delphi?

Tags: delphi, facebook, xmpp

I want to connect to facebook chat from my delphi application , change the status message or post something on the wall? Do u know any way i can acomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Face book chat](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php) uses the [XMPP or Jabber Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)

Other Similar questions on SO

- [jabber-xmpp-library-for-delphi-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145756/jabber-xmpp-library-for-delphi-7)
- [any-complete-library-for-jabber-in-delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181987/any-complete-library-for-jabber-in-delphi)

Exodus is what we plan on trying in house, http://code.google.com/p/exodus/

As For Posting things on the wall, i think you have to register with Facebook to use the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to connect to Facebook Chat with Delphi, check out [this XMPP library for Delphi](http://www.jabberstudio.org/projects/exodus/project/view.php). Facebook chat uses XMPP as its communication protocol.

If what you want is change your Facebook status or post some stuff to the wall, you need to use Facebook API through Delphi. Maybe taking a look al [Delphibook](http://code.google.com/p/delphibook/) might help.

Comment: Is there a download link on the XMPP library page? Most links seem to lead to empty pages.