# Are there any Delphi components for writing Facebook apps?

Tags: delphi, facebook

I'm looking to start writing some small Facebook apps with Delphi - are there any usable components already written to help with this process?  Alternately sample code for Facebook's Graph API or other methods.

Thanks!

Darian

Comment: I started a Facebook Delphi library in Delphi XE to access the Graph API, but it is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to check [this link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=236291). But as they mention in the discussion, it's just a starting point. If you wish complete component (just an API wrapper), you may try to contact the supplier from [this post](http://www.getacoder.com/projects/delphi%20facebook%20component_116787.html).
But I guess, [the solution](http://www.lagorio.net/windows/facebook/) written in Visual Basic will be soon translated to Pascal.
I would do it, if there would be sufficient interest, but there are two facts, which doesn't allow me to do this - I have no time and no Facebook :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, there is Delphi for PHP **XE** with which you can create facebook applications, if you're referring to Delphi(for Windows) I haven't seen or heard about any facebook components or API's.

Comment: It's called RadPHP XE now, you can get it separately or it's included with RAD Studio XE.

Answer (score 1):

This is another question on SO, similar topic

[facebook-chat-in-delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305841/facebook-chat-in-delphi)